# Android how to efficiently implement data caching and configuration change events in fragments?

Tags: android, performance, caching, android-fragments, android-configchanges

I'm confused in finding a better way to implement:

**1)** data caching, as I am fetching data from rest APIs by executing `AsyncTask` in every fragment say 3-4 times, what I want is to reload the data from cache instead of calling the `AsyncTask` again.

**2)** a way to deal with configuration changes events... such as orientation change or some other events.

confusion: are DATA Caching and onconfiguration changes related at all somehow? If so, does only caching code can serve the purpose for both issues?

What I've tried : [here's a project](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/worker-fragments) that does the magic for onconfiguration changes part and
[this library project](https://github.com/mttkay/ignition) can serve the data caching purpose

or should i use the [volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) as recommended in google io 2013?

My MODEL: I am having 1 ACTIVITY that controls and seven other specific fragments that does the execution part. Please type your words if you've any kind of idea how to proceed?

Comment: Well, data caching is basically temporarily saving data to the hard drive.  Configuration changes cause the activity to get destroyed and re-created.  If you want to know the different ways to persist the data in that situation, google "android persistent data storage".

Answer (score 0):

[Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) may totally satisfy your needs. If not, consider using [`LruCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).